# Hash key sorting using perl?

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

I need to sort hash key using perl also i need to allow duplicate in key. So that i planned to check `exists` method in perl
 if it is exists then i increment a last digit then i will store into hash. 
I tried the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use iPerl::Basic qw(_save_file _open_file);
my $xml = $ARGV[0];
my ($xmlcnt,$backcnt,$refcnt,$name,$year) = "";
my %sort = ();
if(($#ARGV != 0) or(not -f "$xml") or($xml!~ m{\.xml$}i)){ 
    print_exit("\t\tSYSTAX ERROR: <EXE> <xml File>\n\n")
};
$xmlcnt=_open_file($xml);
$xmlcnt =~ s{<back(?: [^>]+)?>(?:(?!</?back[ >]).)*</back>}{
    $backcnt = $&;

    while($backcnt =~ m{<ref(?: [^>]+)?>(?:(?!<ref[ >]).)*</ref>}igs){
        $refcnt = $&;
        $name = $1 if($refcnt =~ m{<person-group(?: [^>]+)?>((?:(?!</?person-group[ >]).)*)</person-group>}is);
        $year = $1 if($refcnt =~ m{<year>((?:(?!</?year[ >]).)*)</year>}is);
        $name =~ s{</?(?:string-name|surname|given-names)>}{}ig;
        my $count = 1;
        my $keys="$name $year\E$count";

        if(exists ($sort{$keys})){

            $keys =~ s{(\d)$}{my $icr=$1;$icr++;qq($icr)}e;

            #print"$keys\n";
            $sort{$keys}="$refcnt";

        }
        else
        {
            $sort{$keys}="$refcnt";
        }


print join("\n",keys %sort);
    }
qq($backcnt)
}igse;

    my @keys = sort {
 $sort{$a} <=>  $sort{$b}
# or
# "\L$a" cmp "\L$b"
} keys %sort;
# print join("\n",@keys);
sub print_exit {
    my $msg = shift;
    #print "\n$msg";
    exit;
}
```

Please can anyone tell me what went wrong here?
input:

```
thieooieroh
apple
apple
highefhfe
bufghifeh
```

output:

```
 apple
 apple
 bufghifeh
 highefhfe
 thieooieroh
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ouch! My eyes!  A 25-line chunk of executable code in the replacement part of a substitute command is brutally horrid!  I don't even want to look at it; it is too horrid to be true.  If you must execute the code, put it into a function and invoke the function from the substitute command.

Comment: Here they using substitution, want to store text in hash key. The problem is if the text is already exists at end of the text add integer number for repeated values, and then finally sort the keys.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse xml. ever. Take a look at `die`. It is the proper replacement for your `print_exit`. For preformance reasons, you should avoid `$&` (which you can, if you introduce a matching group and use `$1`). A plain hash is probably the wrong datastructure. You could use a hash of arrays.

Comment: Holy moly, that regex is such a bad idea, I think it's one of the worst I've seen this year. And possibly the previous.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen `s///` inside a `s///` before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a very brief look at your code, it appears that you want to store refcounts as the values in your hash, with the ability to have multiple counts for a single key.  This is easily doable by using a hash of arrays (commonly abbreviated to HoA).  Each key must, by definition, be unique, but the associated value can be a reference, allowing you to store multiple items under that key, or to build even more complex data structures.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %hash;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
  chomp $line;
  my ($key, $count) = split ',', $line;
  push @{$hash{$key}}, $count;
}

for my $key (sort keys %hash) {
  my $values = $hash{$key};
  for (@$values) {
    say "$key ($_)";
  }
} 

__DATA__
thieooieroh,1
apple,2
apple,3
highefhfe,4
bufghifeh,5
```

Output:

```
apple (2)
apple (3)
bufghifeh (5)
highefhfe (4)
thieooieroh (1)
```

If you're not actually concerned with storing multiple data items with each key, but only with the number of times each key appears, it's even simpler.  Change the two loops in the above code to:

```
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
  chomp $line;
  $hash{$line}++;
}

for my $key (sort keys %hash) {
  say $key for 1 .. $hash{$key};
}
```

and you get the output

```
apple
apple
bufghifeh
highefhfe
thieooieroh
```

As for the rest of your posted code, don't try to parse XML with regexes.  Arbitrary XML *cannot* be parsed beyond a very crude first approximation by *regular* expressions because XML is not structurally "regular".  There are many fine XML-parsing modules on CPAN which will parse your XML correctly for you, while also requiring far less effort from you than trying to write your own parser.  Use one of them.  Not regexes.